# How to prevent crackle sound on mp3 playback in Liquidsoap/Icecast setup and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, stream, playback, icecast

I have a local radio (Liquidsoap 2.1.4 + Icecast 2.4.4, both in docker), that broadcasts in mp3 format. My local site has a list of stations; if i click on it, a new stream will play. But at the beginning of playback, a short crackle sound is heard.

I tried already animate volume like this:

```
$(MUSIC).animate({volume: 1}, 500)
...
$(MUSIC).animate({volume: 0}, 500)
```

but it did not help. I also tried to find other ways, but they were all about playing files, not streaming, and did not help me.

Here is a short version of my code without fade in/fade out (jquery):

```
window.onload = function(){
    const MUSIC = new Audio()
    MUSIC.type  = "audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'"
    MUSIC.muted = false

    function clickPlay(){ // click on the station
        MUSIC.volume = volumeLevel // 100% or lower
        MUSIC.src = 'http://ip:port/' + id + '.mp3' // e.g., ip:port/trance.mp3
        play()
    }
    //---

    function play(){
        var playPromise = MUSIC.play()
        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
            playPromise.then(function() {
                //
            }).catch(function(error) {
                MUSIC.play()
            });
        }
    }
    //---

    function pause(){
        if (MUSIC != undefined) {
            MUSIC.pause()
        } 
    }
    //---
}
```

Browser: brave 1.51.118

So, how can i get rid of this crackle sound at the start of playback of the stream?

Comment: do you have an intro file configured in Icecast config? JS itself does not add any cracking to the sound, I think the problem is in the server side. Try listening to the stream using any other player to see if there is noise.

Comment: @AlexParamonov, i already checked it long time ago and rechecked now. If i just open station link in my browser - ip:port/name.mp3 - it will play without any crackling. If i play an m3u playlist in SMPlayer, for example - everything is fine. The crackling issue exists only on the website. And i deleted right now an `<intro>` tag from my `<mount type="default">` section in icecast.xml, but it did not help.